# How to use Combo Box to search a records and display them in the datagrid view in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, combobox

I want to display data into the data grid view using combo box . Say , the user has selected the starting point and the destination from two combo boxes and when the user clicks on the button  , all the trains that are from the selected starting point to the selected destination gets displayed in the datagrid view .I have written a code but it just displays all the records from the database in to the data grid view . Could anyone tell me that how do I search the database from combo box and display it to the datagrid view ? Thanks . Here is my code

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\AMEN\Documents\Railway.accdb"
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource



Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Table1", MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Table1")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view

End Sub

Private Sub Table1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.RailwayDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'RailwayDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.RailwayDataSet.Table1)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'RailwayDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.RailwayDataSet.Table1)

End Sub

Private Sub Table1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.RailwayDataSet)

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query being sent to the database is wrong, you need to send the query depending on the combo box selection in 
sample example in C#

```
strSQL = " Select * from Table1 where field1=  combobox1.selectedvalue and 
field2 = combobox2.selectedvalue " 
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt1)
gridview.dataSource = dt1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying .Is this how I need to write in vb.net also . Actually my project is in vb.net and im trying to access ms acess records . Thanks !